# What is the time complexity of below func?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What is the running time complexity of fun()?

```
int fun(int n)
{
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = n; i > 0; i =i-2)
      for (int j = 2; j < i; j=j*j)
        for (int k=j; k>0; k=k/2)
            count += 1;
   return count;
}
```

is it O(n * lglgn * lglglgn)?
---- 
Edit:
j = loglog(i) times, big iterative value of j can be almost n(for example n=17,max(j)=16)
k= log(j), since the max value of j is at most n. then the max iterative times can be log(n)
so we can say that the big O of this question is O(n* lglgn * lgn)
Since the value of j and k depends on the previous iterative value (i, j), maybe there is better tight answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

We need to count this carefully, because the number of iterations of each inner loop depends in a non-trivial way on the outer loop's variable. Simply averaging for each loop and multiplying the results together will not give the right answer.

- The outer loop runs O(n) times, because i counts from n down to 0 in constant steps.
- The middle loop's values of j are 2, then 2*2 = 4, then 4*4 = 16, and on the m'th iteration, j = 2^2^m. The last iteration will be when 2^2^m >= i, in which case m >= log log i. So this runs O(log log i) times.
- The innermost loop runs O(log j) times, because on the m'th iteration, k = j / 2^m. The last iteration will be when k <= 1, in which case m >= log j. So this runs O(log j) times.

However, it is not correct to multiply these together to get O(n * log log n * log log log n) - because i is not n on every iteration, and j is not log log n on every iteration. This gives an upper bound, but not a tight one. To calculate the true time complexity, you will need to write it as a double-summation, and simplify it algebraically.

---

As a simpler example to think about, consider the following code:

```
for(i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) {
    for(j = 0; j < i; j += 1) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The outer loop runs O(log n) times, and the inner loop runs O(i) times, but the overall complexity is actually O(n). To see this, count how many times `// do something` is reached; the first time the outer loop iterates it'll be 1, then it'll be 2, then 4, then 8, and so on up to n. This is a geometric progression with a sum <= 2n, giving a total number of steps which is O(n).

Note that if we naively multiply the two loops' complexities we get O(n log n) instead, which is an upper bound, but not a tight one.

Comment: thanks kaya , this answer i know. that's why i am asking it here, I want someone to track exactly for the tight answer to this question.

Comment: Well, the question I answered was *"is it O(n * lglgn * lglglgn)?"*, so my answer is to explain why that bound is not tight. I notice that you have edited the question since then to ask for more; it's not really fair to change the question and expect people who have answered it to update their answers accordingly. "I want someone to do X for me" is also not what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score -1):

Using Big O notation:

- With the first outer loop we get `O(N/2)`. You have a loop of N items and you are reducing it by 2 everytime, though you get a total of N/2 loops.
- With the outter loop we get `O(Log(I))`.
- With the most inner loop we have `O(Log(J))`, because you are dividing by 2 your iterator on every loop.

If we multiply the three complexities because they are nested:
`O(N/2)*O(Log(I)) + O(Log(j)) ~ O(N/2*Log(I)*Log(J)) ~ O(N/2*Log^2(N)) ~ O(N*Log^2(N))`.

We get a linearithmic complexity: `O(N*Log^2(N))`

Comment: These are nested loops, not sequential statements; you can't add the complexities together this way. The numbers of iterations of nested loops should be multiplied, except that doesn't work for loops like this where the number of iterations depends in a more complex way on the index variable of the outer loop.